# Add maxlength in form textArea

Tags: laravel, textarea, laravel-blade

The default textArea characters are 255. Now, I want to extend the characters to 2000. How to add maxlength in Form textArea using Laravel Blade?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('comments', 'Comments*') }}
                {{ Form::textArea('comments', null , ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Comments']) }}
                <span class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: have you checked the documentation for laravelcollective? https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html

Comment: @NorrisOduro Yes, some suggests to me to use maxlength attributes but still not working.

Comment: you can write it out in `html` and add it as a `macro`

Comment: HTML `textarea` field support more than 255 character I think

Comment: `{{ Form::textArea('comments', null , ['maxlength'=>'1000','class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Comments']) }}` does this not work ?

Comment: @Demonyowh Already tried that. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the maxlength of the textArea.
e.g.

```
  {{ Form::textArea('comments', null , ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Comments', 'maxlength' => '2000']) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `maxlength` attributes don't work, you can write it out as a `macro`.

open your `AppServiceProvider` and enter the following in the `boot` method.

```
Form::macro('myTextArea', function()
{
    return '<textarea name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" maxlength="2000"></textarea>';
});
```

and just call `Form::myTextArea()` in your form

Comment: Class Form not found in AppServiceProvider

Comment: add `use Form` to the top of the class

Comment: it display <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" maxlength="2000"></textarea> on the UI

Comment: did you add `{{ Form::myTextArea() }}` to your form?

Comment: Yes, thats why I've tried but it only return or display the one what is being returned (<textarea name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" maxlength="2000"></textarea>)

Comment: sorry... `{!! Form::myTextArea()!!}`

Comment: there is an error. It says "The comments may not be greater than 255 characters." under the textarea field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153649/discussion-between-norris-oduro-and-sack).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `textArea` to `textarea`

```
{{ Form::textarea('comments', null , ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Comments', 'maxlength' => 2000, 'size' => '30x5']) }}
```

If the text area has an attribute named "size" it should be in the format "30x5" where the first digit represents the columns and the second digit represents the rows.

Comment: Do you mean you are only able to store 255 chars in db or only input 255 chars max in textarea?